# Additional Authentication in Laravel through Dynamics 365

Tags: laravel, dynamics-365, voyager

We have a Laravel application with Voyager as the admin panel which is working properly as far as admin-auth is concerned. But for the front-end users, we want to implement external authentication through Dynamics-365 (IFD). So, the client already has a database of users in Dynamics-365 which he wants should be able to login by providing their email and a password stored in a custom entity in Dynamics. So, for authenticating front-end users, we need to make a call to the CRM with an email and fetch the data related to that email and then match the password entered by user with that stored in CRM and if they match, I've to authenticate the user.

We are using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/alexacrm/dynamics-webapi-toolkit) package for accessing the Dynamics-365. What I understand is that I need to create a separate guard for front-end customers.

But where do I put the validation code and how do I create the auth once the credentials entered by user match those in the CRM?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm looking to do something similar.